# Ending Mocha Test Using Express, Socket.io and Node-Telegram-Bot-Api

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mocha.js, telegram

## Ending Mocha Test Using Express, Socket.io and Node-Telegram-Bot-Api

I'm writing tests with Mocha for a script that uses express, socket.io and node-telegram-bot-api.

The mocha test doesn't close after running all the tests, so I'm thinking that one of these three is still doing its thing in the background, which is preventing the script from completing.

I added a function that manually closes express (and in conjunction) socket.io (server.close()) but the script keeps running.

My thoughts are that node-telegram-bot-api is still listening for messages. Is there a way for me to kill the connection, similar to the close() function provided by express?

## Update

I have since found out about the [bot.stopPolling()](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/81) function but that didn't seem to work for me.

When I run the mocha test with wtfnode I get the following output:

```
[WTF Node?] open handles:
- File descriptors: (note: stdio always exists)
  - fd 1 (tty) (stdio)
  - fd 2 (tty) (stdio)
- Child processes
  - PID 29442
    - Entry point: /home/user/projectNAME/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha:72
```

Really not sure what to make of that information.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, when mocha test didn't close after all tests passed.
According to this:

> https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit

to avoid false positives and encourage better testing practices, Mocha will no longer automatically kill itself via process.exit() when it thinks it should be done running.
So, I installed [wtfnode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode) package.
My previous output was like yours.
I solved it by adding "_" to "mocha" at package.json path like this:

```
"test": "npm run compile && NODE_ENV=TEST wtfnode node_modules/.bin/_mocha ./dist/**/*.spec.js"
```

And now my output looks like this:

```
    Server stopped.
^C[WTF Node?] open handles:
- File descriptors: (note: stdio always exists)
  - fd 1 (tty) (stdio)
  - fd 2 (tty) (stdio)
- Sockets:
  - 127.0.0.1:43960 -> 127.0.0.1:27017
  - 127.0.0.1:43964 -> 127.0.0.1:27017
  - 127.0.0.1:43966 -> 127.0.0.1:27017
  - 127.0.0.1:43968 -> 127.0.0.1:27017
  - 127.0.0.1:43970 -> 127.0.0.1:27017
- Timers:
  - (5000 ~ 5 s) (anonymous) @ /home/slava/eyescanlab/backend/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:469
- Intervals:
  - (60000 ~ 60 s) (anonymous) @ /home/slava/eyescanlab/backend/dist/backend/src/services/internetConnection.service.js:26
```

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching this from the wrong angle.

Instead of instantiating the class that I was testing in each `it(() => {}` block, it makes more sense to put all that stuff in the `before(() => {})` hook as a class variable.

I solved the lacking telegram function problem by executing process.exit(1) in the `after(() => {})` hook.

That last part is probably not best practice but it solved my problem.